# How to avoid looking-up a dictionary twice for getting/setting key value in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by, key, aggregate

I have a list:

```
lst = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('a', 4), ('c', 5)]
```

and I want to group by the first element of the tuple and append the second element:

```
group = {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2], 'c': [3, 5]}
```

So my code looks like this:

```
group = dict()
for e1, e2 in lst:
    if e1 in group:
        group[e1].append(e2)
    else:
        group[e1] = [e2]
```

What I don't like about this code is that I am looking up for a key in the group dictionary twice, one for the command `e1 in group` and two for the command `group[e1] = ...`

Is there a better way to keep 'a pointer' if the key is found and don't have to look a second time to set the value of this key?
Also, if there is a far better solution using a library please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict
lst = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('a', 4), ('c', 5)]
group=defaultdict(list)

for k,v in lst:
    group[k].append(v)

group
# defaultdict(list, {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2], 'c': [3, 5]})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

> When each key is encountered for the first time, it is not already in the mapping; so an entry is automatically created using the default_factory function which returns an empty list. The list.append() operation then attaches the value to the new list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
group = defaultdict(list)
for e1, e2 in lst:
    group[e1].append(e2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

group = defaultdict(list)

for e1, e2 in lst:
    group[e1].append(e2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `get()` with default value empty list `[]`

```
group = {}
for e1, e2 in lst:
    group[e1] = group.get(e1, []) + [e2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You do with `groupby`,

```
In [38]: from itertools import groupby
In [39]: {g:[i[1]for i in l] for g, l in groupby(sorted(lst),lambda x:x[0])}
Out[39]: {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2], 'c': [3, 5]}
```

Comment: you do not need  the `key` argument in the `sorted` method, the sorting it is done by the first element in the tuple